# What is the significance of failback setting in a SQL AG?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I have a 2-node AG with WSFC setting configured as allow failback between 3am and 7am.

I restarted node 1 at 1am which caused an automatic failover to node 2. However there was no automatic failback between 3am to 7am which has surprised me.

In a SQL AG, is there any significance of the failback setting or this is irrelevant for an AG?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't automatically return the service to the primary replica when it becomes available again after failure. 
The failback, WSFC setting doesn’t really apply to SQL AG the same way as other clustering setups.